# Android app notifications each 15 minutes

Tags: android, background, notifications

I want to codify a notification class in background when app is close or not (or something like whattsapp, instagram that notifies you when a friend sends you a friend request...) so I will make an httprequest each 15 minutes or inversa system with my server or external website. There's a way to make this? I want to send notifications that I can make with the xml data I get with the data request.

Comment: You may better use Firebase Cloud messaging (FCM) and when ever you want to notify the client then you may send a message to the android from your PHP and it will instantly appears in android client. And more interestingly it will recieve it weather your applicaiton is in background or foreground.

Comment: @WajidAli So I can mix Firebase with my own home server or not?

Comment: Firebase provides an API for you send notification to your android/ios/web apps https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send                                                                                                                          or you may see this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

Comment: If it doesnot help you let me know! and you may upvote the comment

Comment: @WajidAli Thanks for the help

Comment: My Pleasure! If you had any problem you can ask again, I have quite experience with using Firebase for different purposes. @Roger RV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do a long polling with android app. If you do so you will use up your bandwidth in a day when you have about 10000 user and it is a very bad pratice. For whatapp what they do is using XMPP server which keep connection alive and foreground but in background they still use something like fcm to push notification. For instagram they just using FCM-like notification which they built it them self who knows since they will not reveal it in public.

If you need notification please use [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) for sending notification rather than make an httprequest each 15 minutes. What fcm does is you will get receive the data which push by the FCM server to your android device no matter you app is closed, in background or in foreground(active). After received the data you can do whatever you like
such as insert to database, show a notification in the status bar in the `onMessageReceived()` method.

Comment: I have a xampp server with the users data and friends data. I see systems like FCM but I don't know if I can costum the notifications with the params I need to setting.

Comment: please do note XMPP is not XAMPP. XMPP is a light weight server, XAMPP is a local virtual machine that build PHP,MYSQL, Apache, phpmyadmin for your. For your second question yes you can fully customize the notification with FCM which you need to create a notification with your android code. All the detail is on the link. Please do mark the answer to let other know this answer is helpful.

Comment: I will see FCM system,  but I'll wait for more answers.

Comment: Its okay just let me know if you need any help.